# Too many open files when reading and writing streams

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to figure out the following error I have :

```
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open '...\logs\...'
```

I am actually reading files, and writing outputs from those files, looping through a function returning a promise.

```
var input = fs.createReadStream(dirpath).pipe(es.split())
        .pipe(es.mapSync(function(line){
          ...
          output = fs.createWriteStream(folderOutput + id + '.xml');

          output.write(documentNode, function(err) {
                input.end();
                output.end();
          });

          output.on('close', function (err) {
            outputClosed=true;
            console.log('output has been destroyed and file has been closed');
            if (outputClosed && inputClosed)
                resolve();
          });

          input.on('close', function (err) {
            inputClosed=true;
            console.log('input has been destroyed and file has been closed');
            if (outputClosed && inputClosed)
                resolve();
            });
          });
        })
  );
```

After a while (processing a lot of files), I have the too many open files error. Any idea of what I am doing wrong there?